# Making a Glyph of more than one unicode character

Tags: fontforge

I would like to know if its possible to combine "**100**" as a Glyph.
-The idea behind is: to make "100" the same WITH as any 2 digit number
-I need only the number "100" being able to manipulate.
-If I have the "100" as a own glyph, I can make my own "100" or adjust WITH
-I know its possible with 2 characters, its called kerning, but that works only for PAIRS!
-So my Question is to make it with 3 characters. Or to simple have my own "100" to edit
-Or more simple: How to combine unicode characters.

Maybe its not even possible, or I just need the right place or word to look for....many thx

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using a [ligature](http://fontforge.github.io/meta/guide-page-3.html). Contextual kerning, which considers more than just a pair of characters, could also be used, but this is far more complex to learn, and it doesn't let you adjust the contours, which you'll probably need to do to make it all fit.

Comment: Maybe its not even possible inside a font to manipulate more than pairs. But maybe to manipulate a font inside windows. For example I could change the mapping in windows and change "100" with a unicode I don't need. e.g. +#-.%/()....and just change the mapping. So when I press "100" it gets changed with a other unicode character.(So I can manipulate this on and draw with custom 100.

Comment: And Important to note that I don't need a font based on unicode. So I am quiet flexible. I just need the numbers and the font needs to work in windows. I think there is a beautiful solution out there somewhere. But I will look into ligature manipulation

Comment: It is possible to manipulate more than pairs in modern fonts such as OpenType. That's the "contextual kerning" I mentioned.